# remove all the list that have a link with href = '#thisisIdOfaDiv'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove all the list `'<li>'` elements which contains any link `<a>` that corresponds to the link `#thisisIdOfaDiv`.

i am doing the following :

```
var id = thisisIdOfaDiv;
$('li').remove($('a[href=#'+id+']'));
```

But i get the error :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'expr.replace(
>   rattributeQuotes, "='$1']" )')

How the remove those lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [.has()](http://api.jquery.com/has) filter

```
$('li').has('a[href="#' + id + '"]').remove();
```

or [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
$('li:has(a[href="#' + id + '"])').remove();
```